# How to say to Wordpress to use caption media library in a gallery?

Tags: wordpress, image-gallery, caption

No one of a "top 5" plugins that I try, use the image-captions of the [media library](https://en.support.wordpress.com/media/)...

**How to setup Wordpress (or plugins) to use/reuse this *standard caption*?**

---

Media library *standard caption* is the caption in the standard interface:

> After you select Edit in List View (or select the image in Grid View) the Edit Media page will load, allowing you to change the default Title, Alternate Text, **Caption**, and Attachment Page Content

Answer (score 1):

Modify whatever plugin you are currently using to add custom code like below. Note, we will have to make adjustment to below code as per the plugin. This is just an example :

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ,'post_status' => null, 'numberposts' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID );

    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
          $alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
          $image_title = $attachment->post_title;
          $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
          $description = $image->post_content;
?>
        <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID); ?>" rel="lightbox" title="<?php echo $image_title; ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/yourfile.php?h=75&w=75&zc=1&src=<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID , false ); ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" width="75" height="75" border="0" /></a>
 <?php } } ?>
```

Edit 1: Let us take [Photo-Gallery Plugin](https://github.com/wp-plugins/photo-gallery)  as the example and try to see what are the options we have to implement changes to reflect your desire result. The above plugin is based on Model View Controller. Also when you install the plugin, it creates own set up tables to maintain info about the Gallery, Theme, Images etc.

So the one better option to start with could be, you made your changes in the respective frontend model and view [frontend/models/BWGModelSlideshow.php](https://github.com/wp-plugins/photo-gallery/blob/master/frontend/models/BWGModelSlideshow.php). I recommend you give special attention to the method `public function get_image_rows_data($id, $sort_by, $order_by = 'asc', $bwg)` in the above model.

And also go through the table structure for the `bwg_image` in [photo-gallery/photo-gallery.php](https://github.com/wp-plugins/photo-gallery/blob/master/photo-gallery.php) before you plan your actual implementation.

Comment: Good [patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(computing)) (!), can you show an example/instruction of use of this code in a popular plugin (ex. NextGEN Gallery, WP Canvas, Envira,  etc.) or, better, in a plugin that have its source at [github/wp](https://github.com/wp-plugins) (ex. photo-gallery, simple-photo-gallery, etc.)?

Comment: Hi @PeterKrauss, honestly speaking I have never used the photo-gallery open source plugin myself. But I will certain try and help you by guiding u in right direction. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry, development in PHP was not my plan with this problem... It is so much complex and time-consuming, than a good plugin choice, or a "how to" guide or setup.... So, **this is not a good answer** for my problem, but is a "correct  answer", so I give the bounty to  it.  PS: readers, I not tested the solution (!)

Comment: Hi @Peter, thanks for the bounty. I am note sure if u have come across  this thread : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/creating-captions-for-images-in-wp-galleries-while-using-lightbox-gallery-plugin , pretty old thread but hope this can help u with ur specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

If that caption is a metafield or st that can be queried by id; maybe some of the plugins have filter/action (or add one?) that can manipulate title to be whatever you like?

Comment: Hi @Mati, the Media Library *caption* is well-defined on my question... Can you describe  a "real case" example where a filter/action was worked?